# how to check(apply 'if'' condition) whether a 'value' of dictionary exists or not

Tags: python-3.x

I have a python dictionary which has a key-value as Success: False or Success:True. I want to apply condition which should say if value of Success is True, "do this".

```
if data_to_be_sent['Success'] =='False':
                    print("Utkarsh")
```

I am unable to go inside the loop , even though a value of 'False' exists in my dictionary.
Below is my dictionary"

```py
{'CorrelationId': 'X', 
    'ValidationType': 'Y', 'Success': False, 'OutputPath': ['<a href=https link</a>', '<a href=https link//key>https link</a>'], 'ValidationDetail': '%'}
```

Comment: `False` is not the same thing as `'False'` - one is a boolean, the other is a string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if not data_to_be_sent['Success']:
    print("Utkarsh")
```

Since `data_to_be_sent['Success']` is a boolean, you can use the form `if <condition>`. You don't need to say `if <variable> == False`.

In addition, `False` is a boolean, while `'False'` is a string. They are not the same.

Comment: Thanks, that worked. Also if this condition is satisfied, I want to grab the links which are present in key: ''''output path'''' . How can I do that?

Comment: @Utkarsh In the if statement, you'd also have a line like `links = [link for link in data_to_be_sent['OutputPath']]`. If you want to parse the actual URLs from the HTML included in the example in your question, I'd suggest looking to [using a regex](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html)